# Does casting a box Forcecage around another spell’s area of effect break concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, concentration, area-of-effect

Part of the description of [*forcecage*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forcecage) states:

> A prison in the shape of a box can be up to 10 feet on a side, creating a solid barrier that prevents any matter from passing through it and **blocking any spells cast into or out from the area**.

If *forcecage* is cast (in the form of a 10-foot solid box) on a point where an existing spell like [*sickening radiance*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sickening-radiance) is centered, does it break the concentration of the previously cast area-of-effect spell? Or would it trap the AoE effect inside the box?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take our [tour] for an easy badge. To answer your question, we need to know what game and, if relevant, what edition you are playing. You can [edit] the question to add a tag with that information. Thanks and we hope to see you again!

Comment: I see you have edited your question in an attempt to further clarify it. However, the reason it was placed on hold in the first place is because we really need to know which game/edition this question is about to be able to give you an appropriate answer. Thank you for participating!

Comment: @Szega I'm nominating this question for reopening, due to the fact that the proposed duplicate question refers to things like cover, or casting a spell after the forcecage is made.  This question asks about casting a force cage over an Area-of-effect spell and what happens to the original spell.  The answers might similar end up being similar, but I find them to be very different questions.

Answer (score 5):

### Interfere with Concentration? No.

Spells do exactly what they say they do.  Force cage doesn't cause the target to lose concentration.  While you can't cast out of the force cage, a spell already cast wouldn't be interfered with unless the other spell requires a constant line of sight...  Witch Bolt would be broken by force cage, for instance, but not because of concentration.

### Or would it trap the AoE effect inside the box? Sorta...

You could cage off the area to prevent people from entering into the area of effect, but it would not stop the effect from happening in that area.