# The Noble Genie Line of Sight/Effect

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, spellcasting, unearthed-arcana

The [Noble Genie Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020-Subclasses01.pdf#page=4) warlock subclass states:

> When you can cast a spell, you can deliver the spell from your space or the bound creature’s space.

My question is, do you need line of sight and/or effect from your square, your bound creature's square, or both?

For example, if the player is in another room can they still cast from that square? It's hard to tell if it's intended to be just the point of origin for the spell, or if you are casting as if you were in that square. I know it's UA and "deliver" is very ambiguous but if anyone has any insight into what this means RAW it would be helpful.

Comment: Related: "[Can a Trickery Domain cleric cast a spell through the Invoke Duplicity clone while inside a Forcecage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/142586)"

Answer (score 5):

### The only condition that changes is the starting point of the spell

The description doesn't say anything about sharing senses with the bonded creature, nor that you can use it senses in any way, so if you need line of sight for a spell to work then you have to see where you are aiming from your position.

For example, you could aim your magic missile at an enemy on the other side of a glass wall and shoot them from your tethered one (if they are both on the other side), but you couldn't do it if it's a rock wall.

Take into account that most spells need a clear path **to the target**, so if you just want to fire a random Fireball in some direction until it hits a wall (the same way you do it inside a Darkness spell), or cast a buff on yourself (the tethered creature in this case), you are not really targeting anything.

If you do target something however, like the aforementioned Fireball, take into account both your line of sight to the target **and** a clear path to the target from the spell's origin.

### However, it doesn't matter anymore

This week a new UA featuring the Genie Wizard [has been published](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/UA2020_SubclassesRevisited_0512.pdf), and it doesn't have anything in common with the last one, so no more tethering :C